# A onSwiped() in the recyclerView within fragment to send back the info to the MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need some help setting up a listener in the MainActivity waiting for a recyclerview item to be swiped off.

```
                @Override
               public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                Log.d(TAG, "whats swiped " + viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() + "   direction: " + direction + "   arrayListCountyNames.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())" + arrayListCountyNames.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                final String s = arrayListCountyNames.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                final String s2 = arrayListStateName.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                final String s3 = arrayListSourceId.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                final String s4 = arrayListID.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
```

I need to get back to the MainActivity because that`s where everything is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of sending your data to other classes.

1. First one is using your own call back methods as this.

First create a model class to store the data you need to send Example:

```
public class Details {
    public String s ;
    public String s2 ;
    public String s3;
    public String s4;
}
```

Then create a Listener(interface) in your fragment as below:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener mListener;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener) {
            mListener = (OnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener) context;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener{
        void onSwipeMyRecyclerView(Details details, int position);
    }
}
```

After that in your onSwiped method, create an object of your details class and assigned all the values you need to pass and call the listener as below:

```
 @Override
 public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

        //your code
        Details details = new Details();
        details.s = s;
        details.s2 = s2;
        details.s3 = s3;
        details.s4 = s4;
        mListener.onSwipeMyRecyclerView(details,direction);
 }
```

and finally implement your listener in your Activity as below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BlankFragment.OnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener {


    @Override
    public void onSwipeMyRecyclerView(Details details, int position) {
        //Do whatever want to do with your data here
    }

}
```

2. Or Second one is easy. You have to use a third party library like EventBus  https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus or Otto http://square.github.io/otto/ follow above links.

Now try and let us know... :)

Comment: Looks good ,but I am stuck with the "mOnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener.onSwipeMyRecyclerView(details,direction);" is giving me a error because the onSwipe is in the fragment class whereas "private OnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener mOnSwipeMyRecyclerViewListener;" is in the MyAdapter class

Comment: So onSwiped method is in your fragment class?

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks for being precise and specific!